# Excepción System.UnauthorizedAccessException en Xamarin

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin, itextsharp

Estoy desarrollando una App en la cual uso iTextSharp para generar un PDF, pero cuando creo el PDF en un dispositivo con android 6.0 o superior da la siguiente excepción:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/mnt/sdcard/DirTest/Test.pdf" is denied.

La ruta existe, el PDF no ya que lo creo en el momento (si existe primero lo borro) y en el Manifest tengo marcado los permisos de escritura en la memoria externa (por más que los esté creando en la memoria local). Estoy probando la App en una tablet con Android 5.1 y no tengo ningún problema, pero tengo otra tablet con Android 6.0 y tira ese error, lo mismo con mi celular (Moto G5S).

¿Alguien tiene idea qué puede ser?
Dejo aquí un fragmento del código de cuando creo el PDF para que lo puedan ver:

```
var directory = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/sdcard", "DirTest").ToString();

if (!Directory.Exists(directory)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "Test.pdf");

if (File.Exists(path)) {
    File.Delete(path);
}

var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

document.Open();
BaseFont Helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
BaseFont HelveticaBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
BaseFont HelveticaCursiva = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
BaseFont HelveticaNC = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;

contentByte.SetFontAndSize(Helvetica, 18);
contentByte.BeginText();
contentByte.ShowTextAligned(1, "Esto es una prueba para el PDF", 300, 820, 0); //Tipo Alineacion (1 Centrado, 2 Derecha, 3 Izquierda), texto, columna, fila, inclinacion
contentByte.EndText();

document.Close();
writer.Close();
fs.Close();

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es simple. `iTextSharp` prácticamente quedó obsoleto, en su lugar hay que usar `iText7` que es su "evolución" por así decirlo.
En este caso, el ejemplo que dejé en la publicación quedaría más o menos así:

```
var directory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/DirTest";

if (!Directory.Exists(directory)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "Test.pdf");

if (File.Exists(path)) {
    File.Delete(path);
}

var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path);
PdfDocument docPDF = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(docPDF);

PdfFont Helvetica = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.CP1252, false);
PdfFont HelveticaBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.CP1252, false);
PdfFont HelveticaCursiva = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.CP1252, false);
PdfFont HelveticaNC = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.CP1252, false);

document.SetFont(Helvetica);
document.SetFontSize(18)
document.ShowTextAligned("Esto es una prueba para el PDF", 300, 820, TextAlignment.Left);

document.Close();

Android.Net.Uri uri;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
file.SetReadable(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ //Android mayor o igual a 7
    string strUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString();
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(strUri);
}else{
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file); //Si el Android es menor a 7 no hay problema en tomar el Uri desde el Java.IO.File
}

Intent verPDF = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
verPDF = SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf);
verPDF.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
StartActivity(verPDF);
```